# Linearly dependent eigenvectors when diagonlising a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I wanted to diagonalise an $n \times n$ matrix $A$. Let $P$ be the matrix of eigenvectors.

Why is it that I need columns of $P$ to be linearly independent? If I had two equal eigenvalues and therefore two equal eigenvectors, can't I just put them side by side and then I will get the eigenvalues come up again in the diagonalized matrix?

Comment: $P$ needs to be invertible!

Comment: Your “therefore” is wrong: Equal eigenvalues don't necessarily mean equal eigenvectors.

Comment: @ScottH. Oh and if we have two linearly dependent columns then the determinant is just $0$ right?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Really? Why not? Surely if you are putting the same number into the same matrix, you get the same set of numbers again?

Comment: @Kaish: As an exercise, find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the $2x2$ identity matrix and what do you get? It of course has an equal $\lambda_{1,2} =1$ for the eigenvalues. Regards

Comment: @Kaish Correct.

Comment: As the two previous commenters said. Of course, the *eigenspace* of an eigenvalue, being the set of all eigenvectors for that eigenvalue plus the zero vector, is uniquely determined by the eigenvalue. Any given eigenvector is not.

Comment: @Amzoti Oh and then when you go to solve it for the eigenvectors, it can take any vector as the matrix is that you multiply $(x \, \, \, y)$ with is just $0$ right?

Comment: @Kaish: For $I_{2,2}$, we have $\lambda_1 = 1, v_1 = (0, 1)$, and $\lambda_2 = 1, v_2 = (1, 0)$. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eigenvectors forming a (maximal) independent set means that they form a basis. This is exactly what is needed; in terms of this basis, the matrix of linear application acts by scaling on each of the individual elements in the eigenbasis; thus the matrix is diagonal.